# Trying to move information to sheet 2 based on a value of a cell from sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 00003002300048421607 | 09 008A00 |
| 00003002300048414074 | 09 013A00 |
| 00003002300048415880 | 30 001A00 |
| 00003002300048418713 | 30 001A00 |
| 00003002300048416955 | 30 002A00 |

Lets say this table is in sheet1, I am trying to have a formula move a row into sheet 2 (a1 to a1, b1 to b1, etc.) if the 1st 2 digit number is less than 13 (01-12). For example on row 2 since the 1st 2 digit value is 09 I'd like that row moved to sheet 2, and on the other hand row 3 starts with 30 so I'd like nothing to happen there. Please let me know if you need anymore information to assist me, thank you :)

Comment: index() with match() and drive the match with left() for the two digits

Comment: This is a whole lot easier to do with O365, which version of Excel are you on?  Also, it’s important to “rethink” your wording when trying to solve an excel problem.  A formula is a script that tells a cell how to retrieve its own value based on other cells.  I “worry” when I see terms like “I’d like that row moved…”  The way to solve this problem is to craft a formula for the cells in sheet 2 that know how and when to retrieve their value from the correct row in sheet 1.  Without O365 this is hard to do, and becomes *very* easy with O365.

Comment: That makes sense @MaxR, I'm on 2016 excel (16.0.5134.1000) at the moment, it's a work program so I'm not able to change it sadly.